# PAUSE/STOP the ros subscriber(callback function) and restart it?

Tags: ros, rosnode, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the tutorial of cv_bridge(here is two lines of code in the tutorial, 1.4 An  example ROS node),

(line 24)image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("in", 1, &ImageConverter::imageCb, this);

(line 61)ros::spin();

Base on this code, the ros::spin() will call the callback function and then always stay in the callback function! So if I want to pause the callback function or subscriber for a while, and then restart it, what should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63988/pause/stop-the-ros-subscriber(callback-function)-and-restart-it?/) by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not how spin works. See the [roscpp spinning documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning)

If you want to stop receiving data you should unsubscribe and resubscribe to start the flow again.  See the [subscriber overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-05-30**:
Thank you ! I try to find the answer in the link of subscriber overview you given. But it seems nothing related to unsubscribe and resubscribe. Then I try like this, the code show in later answer. it will shutdown the subscriber, but I don't know why it doesn't resubscribe.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-31**:
Also, for a temporary pause that needs to happen fairly quickly, you can send a message to your node causing it to start ignoring the original topic until told to resume operation.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-31**:
To unsubscribe shutdown the subscriber or destruct it.  And to resubscribe create a new subscriber.

**Comment by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) on 2013-06-01**:
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;

while(1)
{
image_sub_=it_.subscribe("/ardrone/image_raw", 1,imageCallback);
ros::spin();
......
}

and in the end of imageCallback function I add this code, "image_sub_.shutdown()"

The final result seems, the subscriber will shutdown, but never resubscribe.

---

Originally posted by [anthonyli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4990/anthonyli/) with karma: 11 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1